# Struts 1 and i18n: how put a <bean:message> tag in an img title?

Tags: jquery, struts-1, tooltip

I'm using jquery tooltips.

My strings are in MessageResources.properties files.

I need to take one of them and use it for an img tooltip. This code doesn't work:

```
<html:img src="myimg.gif" title="<bean:message key='msg1'/>"/>
```

Comment: Can you not access the string in your .properties file in your action class and save them in your session and access that session value in your jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3aimg):

> titleKey
>
> The message resources key for the advisory title for this element.

Comment: is there a way to pass a variable to the key string?